# Using Theme Switcher Widget for a real project

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

As far as I understand Theme Switcher Widget is designed for use on demo only pages ("[If you have a demo page using the jQuery UI CSS Framework](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/ThemeSwitcher)...")

Is safe to use it in non-demo pages? Is there any non-demo pages alternative? Any suggestion on implementing a theme switcher?

Note: when I talk about non-demo pages I'm refering to any kind of Internet services, like twitter, stackoverflow or digg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be safe enough to do.  Here is some info on how to use the default ThemeSwitcher:

http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Change-Page-Themes-Dynamically-Using-JQuery-Theme-Roller.aspx'

Here is a rewrite of the ThemeSwitcher widget which enables you to also add your own custom themes in addition to the UI gallery themes:

https://github.com/skamansam/jquery-ui-themeswitcher#readme'